# Powershell script scheduled tasks don't work

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

I have created a backup script using xcopy and it generates log files for me on the current date.

Nevertheless, I wanted to couple it with the task scheduler so that my script runs every night at 7pm but after many tests my script with the task scheduler does not "work".

while by launching it manually everything goes well.
I need your help :)

Here is what I put in my task:
Program/script: C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

Add arguments: PowerShell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\Users\Caeko\Documents\Power\log.ps1"

Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you should remove the application name in the field "Add Arguments". I mean, you only have to add the arguments: Add Arguments: `-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -WindowStyle Hidden -File "C:\Users\Caeko\Documents\Power\log.ps1"`

Comment: Hello nonameyet, i just tried and no it doesn't work :/
Besides, I checked "execute even if no user is logged in", also "execute with maximum permissions" and configured for windows 10.

Comment: Read this topic at Spiceworks: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/390498-running-xcopy-with-task-scheduler. You should use the `net` command and change `xcopy` to `robocopy` command.

Comment: Ok, well I solved my problem.
you just have to fill the field "start in:" with the path where you want your file to be generated. ex : start in : C:\Users\YourName\YourFiles Thanks for your time nonameyet

Comment: I'm glad you solved your problem, but you don't explain what you mean by "it doesn't work".

Comment: I mean by "it doesn't work" that the task scheduler at the beginning did not launch my script that I had planned.

For that I asked a question here to know why my script did not launch automatically although I coupled it with the scheduler.
Upstream, I continued to search and it turned out that I had not filled the field "start in:"